# Access AWS Reserved instance via ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, instance, reserved

I have just created a reserved instance (Linux) on AWS. 
I want to access the server via ssh by "ssh username@hostname"

However I can't seem to find what the reserved instances ip address or domain name is.

I can't find it in the properties nor a column to add with that info.

[image: The reserved instance]

[image: Possible columns to show]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reservation is just a billing feature. Now you need to launch an instance with parameters matching your reservation